# Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl$CancelTask

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jdbc, c3p0

I'm developping a web application in jee and i got this problem only on the server. I'm using  a tomcat 7, hibernate 2 ,mysql, and c3p0 to manage pool connection.

```
nov. 22, 2013 3:15:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could
not load com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl$CancelTask.  The eventual following stack trace       
is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate   
the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:2485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetadataSafeStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:3068)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:3817)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2200)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor42.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:183)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:172)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:188)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1798)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:636)
```